# How do I install Windows 10 on Mac without removing the existing Linux partitions?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition, disk-format

I have a MacBook Air (El Captain) with Kali-Linux dual booted. Well, kind of. It's a 4 GB partition for live and a 15 GB partition for persistency.

So, all I wanted to know is, do I have any possibility of adding Windows onto my internal SSD too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can do it, but the order of installation should go like these:

> 1. Install Apple's Bootcamp and use it to install Windows 10
> 2. Use Windows 10 to shrink the Bootcamp partition, freeing up space to
> 3. Install Linux
> 4. Install rEFInd as a Boot Manager for all 3 OSes

All details are provided by Rob Pickering: 
https://robpickering.com/triple-boot-macbook-pro-macos-windows-10-linux/